# Binding data to a javascript template (jQuery mobile)

Tags: templates, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

To start, I'm trying to show static data into a listview. The code is like this:

```
<ul id="accessList">


</ul>

<script>

    var dataTest = [{"abc":"123"}, {"abc":"456"}];

    (function () {
        $(document).bind("pageinit", function () {
            $("#accessList").html($("#accessTemplate").render(dataTest)).listview();
        }());

    }());

</script>

<script id="accessTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">

    <li>
        <div>{{:abc}}</div>
    </li>
</script>
```

But it's giving me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'render'
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is jsrender.js included above jquery mobile?  Please show us the order of your includes.

Comment: @Scott, I forgot to add the jsrender script... Thanks Scott!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the jsrender script before jQuery Mobile, like Scott suggested.